# Google Analytics sidebar not loading in Chrome

Tags: google-analytics

When I go sign in to my Google Analytics, I get the loading thing on the top of the page that doesn't go away. Also the sidebar `tr#ID-navPanelContainer` doesn't display anything (stays blank).

The rest of the page works fine.

This is only happening in Google Chrome.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Is there a fix for this?

I need the sidebar to get to features such as traffic flow and events

EDIT: Here are some screenshots of what I see. On logging in
[image]

Then if I click `All Accounts`:[image]

And then if I click my account:[image]

EDIT2:

I get this error in developer tools:

```
/analytics/web/#home/a29378725w55476325p56482285/:1GET https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js 
chrome-extension://babchocnjjcibnldbhddhlmdilchnabd/script.js:104Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
analytics.js:1Uncaught Error: setEnhancedReportLoadingScreenEnabled called more than once
chrome-extension://babchocnjjcibnldbhddhlmdilchnabd/script.js:104Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
analytics.js:1705Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

Comment: @ErikdR: How about screenshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, that is some strange stuff, do you have any strange url's in your website?

- You can use only UTF-8 characters when you enter the URL. You cannot
  use the following UTF-8 characters: & = . $ %20 ? ^ #
- If you enter a URL that is not formed correctly, Google Analytics
  prevents you from proceeding until you resolve the error.
- If the URL for your website contains non-UTF-8 characters (for
  example, characters from the Cyrillic alphabet), see this article:
  http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=1082131

Is this a new occurrence, have you just installed google analytics?
You can try and make profile with a new Tracking ID for the website

Comment: No, everything is in ascii chars, also I have it working in FF so I think it's a browser issue.

Comment: Latest chrome version? (Type in chrome: chrome://version/)
Tried disabling/updating your Extensions? (Type in chrome:chrome://extensions/)
Tried removing all your cache etc? (ctrl + shift + delete in chrome)

Comment: Oh and what does the Developer Tools Console say?

Comment: Latest version of Chrome. I do get this error though:
(I edit the question with the Error.

Comment: Figured it out it was the user script `googlePrivacy 1.0` , I got rid of it. Thanks for telling me to look at developer tools

Comment: Try disabling your addons and it also seems your script is executing before the document is parsed.
Try moving the scripts to the bottom of the page just before </body>